# Concourse Pipeline for running ansible playbook

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

I want to create a concourse pipeline for running a ansible playbook. I have a piece of code for that but i am confused with few parameter's.

### Here is my code . Now i am unable to understand which ssh-key should be placed in git type resource how to create and pass to the pipeline . Can anyone help me

resource_types:

- name: ansible-playbook
  type: docker-image
  source:
  repository: troykinsella/concourse-ansible-playbook-resource
  tag: latest

resources:

- name: ansible
  type: ansible-playbook
  source:
  debug: true
  user: user
  ssh_private_key: ((ssh-key))
  verbose: vvv
- name: source-code
  type: git
  source:
  uri: ((git-repo))
  branch: master
  private_key: ((ssh-key))

jobs:

- name: ansible-concourse
  plan:

  - get: source-code # git resource
  - put: ansible
    params:
    check: true
    diff: true
    become: true
    become_user: root
    inventory: inventory/hosts
    playbook: site.yml
    path: source-code